# Defaulting multiple arguments

Tags: c++

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
class Example {
  Foo1 f1;
  Foo2 f2;
  Foo3 f3;
  size_t hash;
};
```

Please note that FooX will be always different classes. I want to add a constructor which assigns the value to each fX element and computes the hash (for cacheing its value).

However I want to be able to omit any number of arguments and assign a default value to the corresponding member of the class. Obviously I could use the defaulting feature of C++:
`Example(Foo1 f1 = DEFAULT4F1, Foo2 f2 = DEFAULT4F2, Foo3 f3 = DEFAULT4F3);`
However for being able to omit f2, I need to omit f3, which I might want to specify. Then I could write a constructor for each possible order, but the amount of constructors grows with the factorial of elements, so for this case:

```
Example(Foo1 f1 = DEFAULT4F1, Foo2 f2 = DEFAULT4F2, Foo3 f3 = DEFAULT4F3);
Example(Foo1 f1 = DEFAULT4F1, Foo3 f3 = DEFAULT4F3, Foo2 f2 = DEFAULT4F2);
Example(Foo2 f2 = DEFAULT4F2, Foo1 f1 = DEFAULT4F1, Foo3 f3 = DEFAULT4F3);
Example(Foo2 f2 = DEFAULT4F2, Foo3 f3 = DEFAULT4F3, Foo1 f1 = DEFAULT4F1);
Example(Foo3 f3 = DEFAULT4F3, Foo1 f1 = DEFAULT4F1, Foo2 f2 = DEFAULT4F2);
Example(Foo3 f3 = DEFAULT4F3, Foo2 f2 = DEFAULT4F2, Foo1 f1 = DEFAULT4F1);
```

I don't want to specify the same constructor that many cases, because in my real case there are more than 3 parameters. I also want to consider forwarding their values (`Foo&& arg` and `std::forward(arg)`)

Edit:
To sum up: desired constructor would act like this, but being able to omit any of the parameters, and use a default value for them

```
Example(Foo1&& f1, Foo2&& f2, Foo3&& f3) :
  f1(std::forward(f1)),
  f2(std::forward(f2)),
  f3(std::forward(f3)),
  hash(doSomethingForIt())
{
}
```

Comment: Use a parameter object

Comment: [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) might come to help.

Comment: XY problem? Bad design?

Comment: Maybe use [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)?

Comment: It still grows significantly with each new member but you could cut the number of required variations significantly if you require the initialization values (if present) be in a particular order. That is, my_class m{f1, f2, f3}; and my_class  m2{f1, f3}; are both legal but my_class m3{f1, f3, f2}; is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a second try to [François Andrieux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57580473/9769768)'s solution and I achieved my requirements. Here is a working example (C++17) of it:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

//Make a unique class for each foo, to prevent implicit casting
template <typename P>
struct Foo{
    constexpr Foo(int x) : x(x) {}
    int x;
};

using Foo1=Foo<struct Phatom_1>;
using Foo2=Foo<struct Phatom_2>;
using Foo3=Foo<struct Phatom_3>;

//Example class
class Example {
public:
    //Default constructor, assingns default falues to all members
    Example() :
        f1(DEFAULT_F1),
        f2(DEFAULT_F2),
        f3(DEFAULT_F3)
    {
    }

    template<typename... Types>
    Example(Types&&... t) : Example() { //First of all, calls the default constructor
        auto paramTpl = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Types>(t)...); //Creates a tuple with the parameters

        assign(f1, paramTpl);
        assign(f2, paramTpl);
        assign(f3, paramTpl);
    }

    void show() const{
        std::cout << "f1=" << f1.x << ", f2=" << f2.x << ", f3=" << f3.x << std::endl;
    }
private:
    static constexpr auto DEFAULT_F1 = Foo1(1);
    static constexpr auto DEFAULT_F2 = Foo2(32);
    static constexpr auto DEFAULT_F3 = Foo3(-1);

    template<typename Type, typename... Types>
    static void assign(Type& el, std::tuple<Types...> tpl){
        struct has_type : std::disjunction<std::is_same<Type, Types>...>{};
        if constexpr (has_type::value){
            el = std::move(std::get<Type>(tpl));
        }
    }

    Foo1 f1;
    Foo2 f2;
    Foo3 f3;
};


int main(){

    Example ex1;
    ex1.show();
    Example ex2(Foo1(1), Foo3(1), Foo2(1));
    ex2.show();
    Example ex3(Foo1(2), Foo3(2));
    ex3.show();  

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I have simplified a bit

Comment: Glad my answer was useful.

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround, not an initialization in C++ sense.

Because you need in advance *all* members of your class, you already know them:

```
class Example {
  Foo1 f1;
  Foo2 f2;
  Foo3 f3;
  size_t hash;
  //default ctor, initializes all members with defaults defined somewhere
  Example() : f1(defaultF1), f2(defaultF2), f3(defaultF3) {}
....
```

Now we add setters:

```
  Example& setFoo1(Foo1 fo1 = defaultF1)
  {
      f1 = fo1;
      return *this;
  }

  Example& setFoo2(Foo2 fo2 = defaultF2)
  {
      f2 = fo2;
      return *this;
  }
....

}; //class Example
```

And then the usage:

```
Example exple;
exple.setFoo2(someF2value).setFoo1(someF1value); //not all setFooX are used
```

Notice that we can call setFooX() in any order.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [Ripi2 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57580659/9607529) I would also add a method which computes the hash and returns an r-value.

```
class Example
{
    Foo1 f1 = DEFAULT4F1;
    Foo2 f2 = DEFAULT4F2;
    Foo3 f3 = DEFAULT4F3;

    size_t hash;

    auto doSomethingForIt();

public:
    Example() = default;

    auto& initFoo1(Foo1&& f) { f1 = std::move(f); return *this; }
    auto& initFoo2(Foo2&& f) { f2 = std::move(f); return *this; }
    auto& initFoo3(Foo3&& f) { f3 = std::move(f); return *this; }

    auto&& finalize()
    {
        hash = doSomethingForIt();
        return std::move(*this);
    }
};
```

This allows for stuff like this to work.

```
void foo(Example&& e);

foo(Example().initFoo1(f1).initFoo3(f3).initFoo2(f2).finalize());
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution where the constructor takes a parameter pack of arguments, forms a tuple with it and tries to reorder the tuple to the desired configuration.

```
#include <tuple>

namespace details {

    // General case
    // In : the type of input tuple with the out-of-order elements
    // Out : a tuple with the desired element order
    template<class In, class Out>
    struct sort_tuple_impl;

    // Implementation with specialization
    template<class In, class ... T>
    struct sort_tuple_impl<In, std::tuple<T...>>
    {
        static auto sort(In && params)
        {
            // Construct another tuple using the output type's elements
            //  to determine the order of the elements
            return std::make_tuple(std::move(std::get<T>(params))...);
        }
    };
}

// Reorders a tuple
template<class Out, class In>
Out sort_tuple(In && params) {
    return details::sort_tuple_impl<In, Out>::sort(std::move(params));
}

// Example types
struct Foo1 {};
struct Foo2 {};
struct Foo3 {};

class Example
{
public:
    // A constructor that takes any kind and number of argument
    template<class ... T>
    explicit Example(T&& ... params) :
        // Make a tuple with the arguments and reorder it according to `decltype(f)`
        f{sort_tuple<decltype(f)>(std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(params)...))}
    { }

private:
    // The elements you want to be able to initialize
    std::tuple<Foo1, Foo2, Foo3> f;
};
```

Usage example :

```
int main()
{
    Foo1 f1;
    Foo2 f2;
    Foo3 f3;

    Example e1{ f1, f2, f3 };
    Example e2{ f2, f1, f3 };
    Example e3{ f3, f2, f1 };
    Example e4{ f3, f2 ,f1 };

    // These fail to compile
    // Example e5{ f1 };
    // Example e6{ f1, f1, f2};
    // Example e7{ f2, f3, f1, f3 };
}
```

Note that if the user provides the same `Foo` more than once or fails to provide one this will produce a compiler error because `std::get` fails if the requested type is not present exactly once. From [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) :

> Extracts the element of the tuple t whose type is T. Fails to compile unless the tuple has exactly one element of that type.

It doesn't produce *great* error messages, but it prevents mistakes.

Edit : This fails the apparent requirement that some elements can be omitted. But I'll leave it here nonetheless as it may be useful. Perhaps another templated function could be used to add the default values to the missing elements.